# Get permissions of a file or folder

Tags: c++, permissions, netapi32

Iam trying to get permissions on file/folder for current user. I found nice article about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/useraccesscheck.aspx). I have tried to run this program but I got few erros and I dont know where I can find solutions to them. I tried to make my own version. Unfortunately when i try:

```
LPWSTR lpszPrimaryDC = NULL;
NetGetDCName(NULL, L"A", (LPBYTE *)&lpszPrimaryDC);
```

I got error: `NERR_DCNotFound`. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that error is returned when it "Could not find the domain controller for the domain specified in the domainname parameter."  Do you have a domain called "A"?  If not, the function is right to fail (and you need to rethink why/how you are calling it).

Answer (score 0):

The only way the code didn't crash and gave me correct answer to question: is file or folder readable?

```
`   
FILE *myFile = fopen(dirPath, "r");
if (myFile == 0) {
    // "File or Dir is not readable
}
`
```

Hope this helps. You can use the same for writing test with "w".